# Where does the value count come from in response.json()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

pretty simple question for some of you out there but, basically I have this line of code

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
      this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: data.count}))
          })
```

And I have no idea why I have to do `data.count` to get the number of entries?
None of the variables in the object returned are called count. So is it a json thing?

Heres what it returned when I console.log data

```
{id: "123", name: "john", email: "j@gmail.com", password: "cookies", entries: 14, …}
id: "123"
name: "john"
email: "j@gmail.com"
password: "cookies"
entries: 14
joined: "2020-06-10T21:36:42.041Z"
__proto__: Object
```

Everything besides proto I have predefined in an object called user.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(data.count)`? Is it perhaps `undefined`? I don't know what passing `{ entries: data.count }` is doing with respect to the rest of your code, but it's possible that it's actually ending up as `{ entries: undefined }`. This doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since `entires: 14` is present in the lower example, but it's my first guess as to where to start.

Comment: Hey, it comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.count` is possibly `undefined` for your use-case. But as data has the property `entries: 14`, so I believe this is what you meant to do,

```js
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
      this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: data.entries /* data.entries instead of data.count */ }))
 })
```

Comment: Yea that worked. Thank you!
How come it wasnt returning an error with ```data.count``` ?

Comment: It's the result of javascript being a dynamically typed language,  `data.count` will simply become the value  `undefined` at runtime instead of throwing an `error` if `count` property doesn't exist on `data`.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: there's your answer — `count` doesn't come from anywhere, since it isn't there. Calling `object.foobar` when `foobar` doesn't exist in JavaScript doesn't throw an error or return `null`, it returns `undefined`, which won't break in a lot of cases.

The joys of loose-typing!

```js
const object = {
  foo: 'one',
  bar: 'two'
}
```

```
> object.foo
// 'one'
> object.foobar
// undefined
```

---

`Object.assign` simply takes its second argument and copies all its properties onto the first, replacing any in its way. What you've got is the same as:

```js
.then(data => {
  data.count = undefined;
  this.setState(data);
});
```

Just that you've got it all in one line. Based on how your code is written, I'm not even sure you need this assignment... you may just be able to `setState` with `data` directly.